# Sending outlook mails with adding followup remainders in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

while sending mail Adding remainders possible in outlook through asp.net c#

CODE:-

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(); 
    msg.To.Add("emailid"); 
    msg.From = new MailAddress("fromid"); 
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true; 
    msg.Body = ""; 
    msg.Subject = "Alert!"; 
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 
    smtp.Host = "host id"; 
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.High; 
    msg.Headers.Add("X-Message-Flag", "For Your Information"); 
    msg.Headers.Add("Reply-By", "08/06/2015 13:05:00"); smtp.Send(msg);
```

Comment: what do you want here ?

Comment: i need to send mail(outlook)  with remainder

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1435.html) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/700211/Csharp-SMTP-Configuration-for-Outlook-Com-SMTP-Hos) You need to make changes accordingly

Comment: yaa i look!..Aleady mail is sending no issue but now i need to add remainder in that mail

Comment: check the reference [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5776/How-to-Create-Birthday-Reminders-Using-Microsoft-O)

Comment: while sending messages in outlook mail we need to add reminder. We no need to use appointment reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean reminder not remainder.

Please see below for what you would need to add to your code

```
DateTime replyDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Headers.Add("X-Message-Flag", "Follow up");
msg.Headers.Add("Reply-By", String.Format("{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", replyDate));
```

Comment: but the outlook reminder icon not showing in inbox mail. Pls check @wingyip

Comment: thanks friends we get the solution after adding below lines  message.FlagStatus = OlFlagStatus.olNoFlag;
message.FlagIcon = OlFlagIcon.olRedFlagIcon;